# PHP primary key table from foreign key

Tags: php

### Table 1: books (book_id as primary key)

```
book_id|title
1      |apple
2      |banana
3      |volkswagen
```

### table 2: genre (genre_id as primary key)

```
genre_id|name
1       |fruits
2       |cars
```

### Table 3:multiple (id as primary book_id and genre_id as foreign key) //to put more genre in 1 book

```
id|book_id|genre_id
1 |   1   |  1
2 |   3   |  2
3 |   2   |  1
```

I wanted to show all books with genre as fruits on alphabetical order my code is:

```
<?php
include "mysql-connect.php";
$sql = 
    "SELECT title 
    FROM books
    INNER JOIN multiple ON book.book_id = multiple.book_id
    VALUES ('1')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "" . $row["title"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Still showing 0 results after changing the values

Comment: `multiple.book_id = genre_id` can't work - you aren't comparing like to like.

Comment: Why do you match book_id and genre_id? You need to match `book.book_id` with `multiple.book_id` and `genre.genre_id` with `multiple.genre_id`.

Comment: this one is missing the `genre` table and the `ON` is messed up

Comment: “... ON book.book_id ... “ needs to be “... ON books.book_id ...”

Comment: Whats this? `VALUES ('1')` part of an Insert in a Select query.  Probably not going to work instead try `WHERE multiple.book_id = 1` or something.  Whatever 1 is supposed to be, I don't know, neither does MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats this?

```
SELECT title 
FROM books
   INNER JOIN multiple 
   ON book.book_id = multiple.book_id VALUES ('1')
```

Doesn't look like a valid SELECT query to me, where is the `WHERE`.  Typical Values is uses in insert

```
  INSERT INTO multiple (id) VALUES (1)
```

Probably you need something like this

```
SELECT title 
FROM books
   INNER JOIN multiple 
   ON book.book_id = multiple.book_id
WHERE
   some_column = 1
```

What this is `some_column` I have no idea.

Comment: Some_column will be the genre of the book, if I click on fruits, books should show everything in category of fruit